This browser or app may not be secure.Learn more Try using a different browser.If you're already using a supported browser you can try again to signin
While I am running a automation script in chrome using selenium java in between there was google sign in I am able to enter the email id and after the clicking next I am getting this error
This browser or app may not be secure.
Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you're already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in.
How to resolve this error?
I tried to automate the Google sign through selenium java. But I am not able to sign in. How do I fix this error.

The site is detecting that you are using Selenium and blocking you.
